# XNA RenderTarget2D limitations of size

Tags: c#, xna, resolution

I have been using XNA to make a PC game and I am doing lighting with RenderTarget2D by drawing the world stuff in one and then drawing the lightmask stuff in another. Anyway I wasn't running into any problems at first using my 1920x1080 monitor, but I just upgraded to a 27" 2560x1440 S-IPS monitor and now I'm getting an error because my monitor resolution is set higher than 2048 and that's apparently the largest size a texture can be.

It's trying to draw a texture of size 2560 by 1440 so I need to find a way around that limitation. I suppose with large screens I could somehow split it into multiple RenderTarget2Ds. My issue with that is how I pass in the light mask:

```
drawMain();
drawLightMask();

ScreenManager.SpriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.AlphaBlend);
lightingEffect.Parameters["lightMask"].SetValue(lightMask);
lightingEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();
ScreenManager.SpriteBatch.Draw(mainScene, new Vector2(0, 0), Color.White);
ScreenManager.SpriteBatch.End();
```

I'm sure others have had to deal with this issue so maybe someone has some ideas on how I could approach this 2048 limitation?

Edit: Another thought.. perhaps when I detect that have a large resolution I just set it lower instead of default setting it to their current resolution. That way wouldn't really have to worry about it. The problem with this way is that in fullscreen mode it's changing their screen's resolution so when they exit the game it has to change resolutions again and is kind of messy. Then in borderless winowed mode the window is smaller but it doesn't seem to change your resolution.

Comment: I assume you use the Reach profile. Is switching to HiDef an Option for you?

Comment: Awesome! I just read into the differences and I had no idea about HiDef. I've only been working on WP7 games the past 2 years. It appears the size goes up to 4096 and that would more than take care of my problem without having to hack it together.

One question: "Xbox 360, and any Windows PC with a DirectX 10 (or equivalent: see below) GPU" They'd need to have a GPU that supports DirectX 10 it seems. DX10 is quite old now though so this doesn't seem like a big issue. How about laptops? Do they tend to come with GPUs that support DX10?

Comment: I've read into it a bit more about found the answer to my question. That solves my problem thanks!